# Transforming a matrix into a partial averages one

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 320*25 matrix that I want to transform into a 64*25 matrix in this way: each row of the new matrix should have the averages of every 5 rows of the old one (and then they will be normalized by a certain vector in a similar way). Below you can see how I've been trying to implement this:

```
for (x in c(1:64)){

      helping.matrix[x,] = colSums(original.matrix[((5*(x-1)+1):5*x),])/sum(vector[((5*(x-    1)+1):5*x)])

}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work, returning the following error:

> Error in inherits(x, "data.frame") : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this might do it - if you have numeric values without NA:s...

```
m <- matrix(runif(320*25),320)
k <- 5
m2 <- rowsum(m, rep(seq(nrow(m)/k), each=k))/k
```

Comment: Simpler than I originally thought!

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with the way you've tried to impliment this. First, it helps to make the example reproducible:

```
original.matrix <- matrix(1:(320*25), nrow=320, ncol=25)
```

Second, if you are going to use a for-loop, you need to initialize an object to hold the results:

```
helping.matrix <- matrix(nrow=64, ncol=25)
```

OK, now let's take a look at your code.

```
for (x in c(1:64)){
helping.matrix[x,] = colSums(original.matrix[((5*(x-1)+1):5*x),])/
```

The indexing expression here is pretty wild, and does not do what you want it to. For example, when x = 2, `(5*(x-1)+1):5*x` = 12, 10. That doesn't match with your stated goal. at x = 9 the expression returns values greater than the number of rows in original.matrix, which is why you get the "out of bounds" error. The next problem occures when we get to

```
vector[((5*(x-1)+1):5*x)])
```

Here you are trying to index `vector` as though it were a data object. But vector is not a data object, it is a function. Maybe you want `c((5*(x-1)+1):5*x)`? Anyway it's not clear from your question exactly what this secton of code is intended to do, so I can't really offer much in the way of suggestions here.

OK, so let's make a fresh start. The way I would approach this problem is by making an index vector that maps on the the groups you want to apply your summing function to:

```
groups <- rep(1:(320/5), each=5)
```

Next, use a loop or an apply-family function to iterate over the groups. The for-loop approach would look something like

```
helping.matrix <- matrix(nrow=64, ncol=25)
for(i in unique(groups)) {
helping.matrix[i,] <- colSums(original.matrix[groups == i,])
}
```

and the apply-based approach would look like

```
helping.matrix <- Reduce(rbind, by(original.matrix, groups, colSums))
```

I've left out the part that is supposed to "normalized by a certain vector" because it's not clear to me what is actually supposed to happen there.

Comment: I had already defined the helpin.matrix. When I was indexing I tried to do this: For x=1 for example, we have 5*(1-1)+1=1, and 5*x=1 so `helping.matrix[1,] = colSums(original.matrix[((5*(1-1)+1):5*1),])` which in turn I hoped it would mean `helping.matrix[1,] = colSums(original.matrix[(1:5,])`. (Rows 1 to 5 of the matrix). The `:` was not meant to imply division. Same with the vector. This indexing indeed works even with vectors! Your second-to-last code was what I was initially going for! Thanks

Comment: @DonC Well `(5*(x-1)+1):5*x` does work for x = 1. But that's the only value of x that works. Take a look at `for(x in c(1:10)){cat(paste("x =", x, ": "), (5*(x-1)+1):5*x, "\n")}`. And yes, indexing works with vectors, but not with the `vector` function. For example, `c(1:10)[1]` is perfectly reasonable, but `vector[1]` is not (unless of course you saved a vector named vector, in which case see `install.packages("fortunes"); library(fortunes); fortune("dog")`).